# Converting circular structure to JSON - error while copying array of elements to another array and return back to original array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a requirement to copy array of elements to temporary array and again return back to the original array. Finally i have to save all the state items.

But while do this process am getting error

> "Converting Circular structure to JSON" in    `"this.props.save(this.state.item);"`
> line.

Please find my code and the error below. How can I overcome this error?

> Error :
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Please find my code below.

```
handleAutoSplit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var logs=item.order_logs;
    var oldLogs =[];
    oldLogs.push(logs);
    
    logs.push.apply(logs,oldLogs);
    this.props.save(this.state.item);
}
```

Comment: don't push a copy of the whole thing onto itself? you can also clone before you push.

Comment: So,here how do i clone..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes worked for me.

Instead of .push(), have to use .splice(0)

```
Example: oldLogs=logs.splice(0);
```